# Change font style for pdf's using Preview

Tags: pdf, preview

As shown in the screenshot there are no options for changing the font under tools. I went through all main menu options and no features for manipulating the color, size, etc are there.

This should be a dead simple operation - any tips here?

[image]

**UPDATE**  I had found references to preview having the ability to modify the text/font characteristics - specifically in the place my screenshot shows. They are not there however: is this a Yosemite specific limitation? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4674837?start=0&tstart=0

**Another update**  One of the answers provided download links for pdfs. I have selected text field and right clicked. The screenshot follows: There are not any options for changing the font/font size: only the color. What is different for me?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On Yosemite (Preview 8.0), hit shift-command-A or select "Show Markup Toolbar" from the "View" menu:

[image]

Find font options by clicking on the italic A:

[image]

Comment: This is great, but the change doesn't stick for me: when I start a new note it's back to a default which is too small.  Is there a way to change the font and have it stick?  (OSX 10.14.6)

Comment: Workaround to the above: type in all the fields too small (zoom in if needed).  Then select them all with shift-click (not cmd-click).  Then change the size in the font selector shown in @SigmaX's answer

Comment: On ElCapitan the option was well hidden again (and not in the View-Toolbars menu any more) - Shift-cmd-A did the trick

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the boxes that come with the pdf cannot be modified in terms of font size or type.  When you open the briefcase in the pdf (using Preview), you can modify the font, then create a new Text box (using T), and move it in the field you want to fill, and start typing.  This will work.

Answer (score 4):

I realize that you've likely moved on by now, but for anyone else searching for this feature:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thx - i am awarding. But it *is* irksome not to include these options in the menu.

Comment: This answer is helpful but when looking at another available answer it shows how to access from the menu bar: this is a nuance only but does fit my keyboard driven style bit better.

Comment: This doesn't change the font of entered text, only annotated text.

Answer (score 2):

Writable or fillable PDF files allow you to include text directly on the PDF file and save the document as if you were filling it out with a pen or pencil. Your Mac includes the Preview application built into the operating system that comes with all the tools you'll need to work with PDF documents. Use the extended toolbar to change the Font of your text when filling out a writeable PDF
In another word, you can change the font size when you fill in PDF-based forms . Read more at [How to Change Font on a Writable PDF on a Mac](http://www.ehow.com/how_12121037_change-font-writable-pdf-mac.html)

you can download the example file from [here](http://www.pdfill.com/example.html#e1)
Fill out form in PDF you can change the font this way[image]

Comment: Those instructions do not reflect the options actually presented to me: specifically the following Font selection window does not show anywhere: "Click the 'A' button on the toolbar to open the 'Font' selection window."

Comment: What Nelson is sayingg is that those options only apply to text you add in text entry fields of a pdf form, not text that already existed the first time you opened the pdf in Preview.

Comment: I changed my answer, you can download the sample form and try

Comment: Yes i understand. I do not see those options for *new* text entry fields.

Comment: OK I did.   Please see updated OP: there are not any options for changing the font/font size: only the color. What is different for me?

Comment: Please put quote marks around the first part of your answer, since you copied and pasted it from someplace else and did not write it yourself.  Also, the linked article now redirects to a non-Mac-specific article on Adobe reader.  The original is visible here: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kJXSUwV1SssJ:www.ehow.com/how_12121037_change-font-writable+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: This does not help or change the font size in PDFs when typing in a field.

Comment: link - http://www.ehow.com/how_12121037_change-font-writable-pdf-mac.html doesn't work anymore @nelson

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kJXSUwV1SssJ:www.ehow.com/how_12121037_change-font-writable+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us @SigmaX doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

A work around for changing the font size in Writable/Fillable PDFs is to open the PDF in Safari (by dragging the PDF to the Safari icon in the dock). I wasn't able to set a custom font size but I did find that Safari shrunk the font to fit the box once I moved focus onto the next box. It doesn't do that in Preview.

Comment: Holla! Thanks for the tip, man. A PDF form was giving me fits in Preview, Firefox, but in Safari, it printed out beautifully! +1

Answer (score -1):

Writable or fillable PDF files allow you to include text directly on the PDF file and save the document as if you were filling it out with a pen or pencil. Your Mac includes the Preview application built into the operating system that comes with all the tools you'll need to work with PDF documents. Use the extended toolbar to change the Font of your text when filling out a writeable PDF
In another word, you can change the font size when you fill in PDF-based forms . Read more at [How to Change Font on a Writable PDF on a Mac](http://www.ehow.com/how_12121037_change-font-writable-pdf-mac.html)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are using the free version of Adobe Acrobat/Reader.

On the Windows side of things if you are using Adobe Reader there is no UI or interface for changing the font.  If you are using Adobe Acrobat Pro/Standard you can change the font.

One workaround I have found is copy some text with the font you want to use from another application and paste it into the PDF form fill field.  Please note this will only work if the PDF form has rich text formatting enabled.

Good luck!

Comment: seems as good an answer/approach as any.  The "copy to another app and then copy it back" has applied in other situations such as doing strikethrough in gmail (no native support)

Comment: The question is about Preview on Mac OS X, not Adobe Reader.

Comment: Did my suggestion of copying the formatting (with font) from another application and pasting work?  I unfortunately cannot test since I don't have a Mac with Preview in front of me.

Comment: No it did not work. Why is this the selected answer?